# How to remove index.html and exclamation sign(!) from URL using AngularJs ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My state configuration js [image: Here]

Now, my URL look like this

[image]

I want to remove index.html and (!) from my URL. Like as following image
 [image]
**How to do achieve this?**

Comment: You should avoid posting and image of the code, since people won't be able to test the code and reproduce the error you having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult the documentation for `$location` methods `html5Mode` and `hashPrefix`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

```
$location.hashPrefix('');
```